# How to configure passport.js with mysql without sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

This is my first time asking a question in any forum. Please do correct me if I am doing something wrong in any way.
So as you all know it is very easy to use MongoDB with passport.js but there is next to no information in setting passport.js with MySQL. I tried but it just doesn't work. Explaining everything here step by step:
Below is the passport.config file. Here I am also console logging the user - console.log(user) - just to see if it is getting the data or not. So the thing is that it returns undefined.
Then the next console log inside the if condition gets logged as it would since 'user' is undefined.
Now please go below this passport.config code I have posted here. Will explain further.

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

const initialize = (passport, getUserByEmail) => {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
      console.log("no user exists");
      return done(null, false, { message: "no user exists with that email" });
    }
    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        console.log("incorrect password");
        return done(null, false, { message: "incorrect password" });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      done(e);
    }
  };
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
      },
      authenticateUser
    )
  );
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
    console.log("serialized");
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id));
  });
};

module.exports = initialize;
```

Now I am including the code for the file where I am initializing passport. Here it is:

```
const initializePassport = require("../passport.config");
initializePassport(passport, (email) => {
  const sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM organizer WHERE email = ?";
  db.query(sqlQuery, email, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(rows[0]);
      return rows[0];
    }
  });
});
```

I am using the console log here to see if I am able to get the user from the database and it is working. But like I mentioned at the top - First the undefined is getting logged since user is taking undefined from getUserByEmail(). Then the if(!user) condition gets checked and 'no user exists' gets printed. Finally this console log of the user data from the code above gets printed. So what I have understood by far is that this is supposed to get executed first so that the user variable gets the user data. But that is not happening and I have no idea why. I feel like it is something so easy that I can't wrap my head around it or idk.
If any good soul could help me out then please do so as I am losing my mind now ^_^.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
So I tried using a promise in the getUserByEmail() and it worked as I thought but I still don't know why it wouldn't work without it. I was returning the entire user to this function previously but it just didn't work. Here is the change that I did. I am using this function in the same file passport.config. If anyone can explain as to why I had to use a promise for it to work then please go ahead. Thank you.

```
let getUserByEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM organizer WHERE email = ?";
    db.query(sqlQuery, email, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log(rows[0]);
        let user = rows[0];
        resolve(user);
      }
    });
  });
};
```